# Recovery tag needs to stop recovering

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I think that the [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) Tag is far too broad as there are so many different types of recovery (which also have tags for them) such as [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), [password-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery), [partition-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition-recovery) and so on. I think it needs to be split up into different types of recovery. Then obviously Axe the [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) tag.

Comment: PS I don't know how to make the tags actual tags like most of the guys have on here so if someone could help me out with an edit I'd appreciate it

Comment: For tag markup use `[tag:tagname]` formatting

Comment: ahh thank you I will try that :)

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to take it a bit further and deprecate [tag:partition-recovery] in favor of [tag:data-recovery]?

Comment: I agree with that yeah

Comment: for anyone checking up on this - I've been deleting recovery bit by bit since april 2017

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completely agree with you. Checked first 50 question of tag - found no reason to keep it.

Moreover, a lot of questions tagged with [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) tag also have [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), [password-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) and[partition-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition-recovery) tags with them which makes [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) tag unmeaningful.
Another part of questions use 2 tags e.g. [partition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition) and [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) in place of [partitiion-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partitiion-recovery), so they can live without [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) too.

---

And [this](https://superuser.com/questions/763259/do-you-want-to-format-it-message-when-open-partition) question is probably the best evidence for removing it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>After several months of trickle edits, and many small bites, the tag has been removed from all the questions.</strike>

Tagliminated. Tagnnihilation. Tagatomised!

It seems I missed... quite a lot. It still lives :(

Comment: the hell? I thought I got em all. Feel free to (slowly and in your own time) edit them.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. One at a time, not flooding the main page too much. Thank you.

Comment: Done. My Archaeologist badge is fairly earned.